# What's the usage of JUnitCore.runClasses?

Tags: java, junit

I've seen some examples showing that running a JUnit class with the `JUnitCore.runClasses(Test.class)`. However, we can easily run the JUnit test classes by right clicking the class file and "Run With->JUnit" in most IDEs. Then, my question is: with the IDEs, what's the usage of `JUnitCore.runClasses`? Is it still necessary to write JUnit classes using `JUnitCore.runClasses`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JUnitCore#runClasses` is usually used when you want to write a program to tests (i.e., a runner).
Since you're running from inside an IDE, there's probably no reason for you to use it in this scenario.